# Simulation takes very long, how could performance be improved?

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe, markov-chains

I am currently doing a markov chain simulation with the `markovchain` package, and an inner- and an outer-loop. In total 175,2 million values should be inserted into a dataframe, the reproducible example code is below. This has been running for 40+ hours now, and I was wondering how I could speed this up? And I am curious whether someone could give me an indication on how long it might take to finish the calculation.

I've already improved the code by using the `profvis` package.

```
library(markovchain)
library(dplyr)
library(expss)



#States and creation of Markov transition matrix
Locations <- c("Home", "Bakery", "Grocery", "Home-Bakery", "Home-Grocery", "Bakery-Home", "Bakery-Grocery", "Grocery-Home", "Grocery-Bakery")

matrixExample <- matrix(sample(runif(81, min = 0 , max =1), replace = FALSE ), nrow = 9, ncol = 9)

matrixExample <- matrixExample / rowSums(matrixExample)
colnames(matrixExample) <- Locations
rownames(matrixExample) <- Locations

matrixExample <- as(matrixExample, "markovchain")


mcListLoop <- rep(list(matrixExample), 96)
mcList <- new("markovchainList", markovchains = mcListLoop)

z <- 10
numDays <- 365
k <- numDays * 96
battery <- 72.5

km <- runif(9, min = 5, max =120)
Locations <- c("Home", "Bakery", "Grocery", "Home-Bakery", "Home-Grocery", "Bakery-Home", "Bakery-Grocery", "Grocery-Home", "Grocery-Bakery")

averageDistance <- data.frame(cbind(Locations, km))
averageDistance$km <- as.numeric(averageDistance$km)


Iteration <- rep(seq(1:96), 365)

#Recreate dataframe
df <- data.frame(Iteration, sample(Locations, k, replace = TRUE))


df <- rmarkovchain(n=365, object = mcList, t0= "Home", include.t0 = TRUE)

#To estimate the size of list
allDf<- rep(list(df), z)


#Start of the loop
for(y in 1:z){

  df <- rmarkovchain(n=365, object = mcList, t0= "Home", include.t0 = TRUE)
  df$Begin <- 0
  df[1,3] <- battery
  df$Still <- ifelse(df$values == "Home", 1, 0)
  df$KM <- vlookup(df$values, averageDistance, lookup_column = 1, result_column = 2)
  df$Load <- ifelse(df$Still == 1, 2.75, 0)
  df$costDistance <- df$KM * 0.21
  df$End <- 0
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
  df$reduce <- rep(seq(1:97), numDays)
  df <- df %>% filter(reduce != 97) 
  df$Load <- ifelse(df$reduce <= 69 | df$reduce >= 87, df$Load, 0)




            for(i in 1:k) {
      mainVector <- df[i,3]
      extra <- df[i,6]
      subtractingVector <- df[i,7]


      mainVector <- ifelse(mainVector < battery, pmin(mainVector + extra, battery),  mainVector )

      newMain <- mainVector - subtractingVector
      j <- i + 1
      df[j,3] <- newMain 
      }


allDf[[y]] <- df

}
```

In the inner-loop the following happens:
In the same observation of a dataframe I have the start capacity of a battery [i,3] and whether it charges [i,6] (when parking) or discharges [i,7] (when driving). The next observation [j,3] should have the start capacity in the first observation [i,3] corrected for the amount of (dis)charge (either [i,6] or [i,7])

I am running this with an i7-8665CPU @ 1.90GHz with 16gb RAM

[image: Profvis run with z being 10]

Comment: some variables still not defined :)

Comment: You write that you have profiled the code. Why don't you show the profiling output in your question? If most of the time is spent in `rmarkovchain` there probably isn't much you can do, except parallelization.

Comment: Variables defined (did a clean run), double loop removed and picture of profvis included.

Comment: Looks like a lot of time is spent with subset assignment, subsetting and `ifelse`. First of all, `ifelse` has no place in efficient code, instead use subset assignment. Then, you might benefit from using data.table due to its fast subsetting and its fast in-place assignment (with the `:=` operator). And of course, iterating over the rows of a data.frame is bad and should be avoided at all costs (try to use vectorization instead and if you can't do that, at least use another data structure, data.frame subsetting is sloooow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match your current calculations you could just replace the inner loop with this:

```
  mainVector <- rep(0, nrow(df) + 1L) # pre-allocate resulting vector
  state <- battery # state at each iteration
  extra <- df[, 6]
  subtractingVector <- df[, 7]
  mainVector[1] <- state # add to resulting vector
  for (i in 1:k) {
    if (state < battery) state <- min(state + extra[i], battery)
    state <- state - subtractingVector[i]
    j <- i + 1L
    mainVector[j] <- state
  }
  df[nrow(df) + 1, ] <- NA # add NA row, so we can add longer vector to df
  df[, 3] <- mainVector
```

Here we separate `data.frame` columns as vectors before loop and store results in vector.
We add the resulting vector to `df` after loop, as lot of time in loop was spend on this operation + adding the new `NA` row at end of `df`.

This should be significantly faster, but other improvements could be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems not to run as expected, there are multiple variables incorrectly defined and two identical loops. But I will guess that the inner loop is written badly.

If you have some `df` with charges/discharges:

```
df <- data.table(charge = c(0, 0, 1, 2), discharge = c(1, 2, 0, 0))
```

some initial state:

```
b <- 1
```

and you want to calculate all the states then:

```
df$change <- df$charge - df$discharge
df$cumchange <- cumsum(df$change)
df$battery <- df$cumchange + b
df
#    charge discharge change cumchange battery
# 1:      0         1     -1        -1       0
# 2:      0         2     -2        -3      -2
# 3:      1         0      1        -2      -1
# 4:      2         0      2         0       1
```

I think that you want something like this for the inner loop.
This should be much faster, if adjusted for your needs correctly.

P.S. As Roland mentions after this improvement `rmarkovchain` probably will be the bottleneck.